# Using LIKE with prepared statement

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a statement I wish to execute to find if a column containing a string contains a certain value.

```
+----+------+
| id |  st  |
+----+------+
|  0 | 2183 |
|  1 | 5820 |
|  2 | 2984 |
| ...|  ... |
+----+------+
```

Say I wish to find all rows where `st` contains a 1, I would use these where conditions:

```
WHERE st LIKE "%1%"
OR st LIKE "1%"
OR st LIKE "1"
OR st LIKE "%1"
```

But how do I do this in a prepared statement?

```
$ps = $db->prepare("
    SELECT id
        FROM table
        WHERE st LIKE "%:a%"
        OR st LIKE ":a%"
        OR st LIKE ":a"
        OR st LIKE "%:a"
");
$ps->execute(array(
    ':a' => $var
));
```

This doesn't work evidently.

Comment: The `%` sign must be part of `$var`  not part of the prepared Statement. also you only Need. "%:a%" it include all other parts of your where  clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` sign must be part of `$var` not part of the prepared Statement. also you only need `%:a%` it include all other parts of your where clause

```
$ps = $db->prepare("
    SELECT id
        FROM table
        WHERE st LIKE :a
");
$ps->execute(array(
    ':a' => "%".$var."%"
));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ps = $db->prepare("
    SELECT id
        FROM table
        WHERE st LIKE :a");
$ps->execute(array(
    ':a' => "%".$var."%"
));
```

Try above code.
And one more thing if you require rows which contains `1` in it,then there is no requirement of 4 like condition you only can achieve using `'%1%'`.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Do not add code only. Explain what you have done and why.